# Superimpose filtered subsection over GPUImageView and capture it

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

First of all, sincere thanks to Brad Larson and contributors for an awesome library.
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

...trying to build a basic tool capturing a filtered still image.  My main view is a GPUImageView - which I want to fill the visible screen.

I want to add a crop filter on top of the main stream with its own filter chain and preview filters and capture just that subsection.  It'd look like a live, unfiltered stream on the background with a subsection with filters applied. (Hope that makes sense.)

I can't figure out the correct way to chain the filters and view to achieve this or if its even possible.

I've tried adding two views to the camera chain -- with a smaller one over the background and which has the desired filters.  This works for the preview but when I attempt to capture it (using the current filter on the smaller view) I keep getting a memory exception.  I'm not certain but it seems the StillImageCamera doesn't support this config? This config looks like:

```
Camera
-> Background GPUImageView
-> CropFilter - (desired inner rect)
--> various other filters
---> Inner GPUImageView (super imposed on top of background view)
```

The other approach I've tried is to just have the one GPUImageView but fork at some point in the filter chain.  One branch leads to the rendered GPUImageView and another to the specific filtered view that I want to capture.  This seems to be the correct strategy and I can capture the desired filter chain without crashing, but the capture image keeps coming back blank. It also has the drawback that I'm not able to show the filtered view in the sub-rect as described above.
This config looks like:

```
Camera
-> Outer CropFilter  (0,0,1,1) -- just used in order to have a base filter
--> Background GPUImageView
-> Inner CropFilter - (desired inner rect)
--> various other filters
```

Basically, I want to:
1) Show/Preview the Inner Crop Filter chain over the background GPUImageView
2) Capture a still of that Inner Crop Filter chain

Would appreciate any guidance as to whether and how to achieve this.